# por que no me muestra ningun resultado en consulta con comodin en access desde c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

buenas tardes a todos o dias , veran tengo un problema y me encuentro algo desesperado , tratare de resumirlo y decirlo en la formas mas clara posible , tengo unas tablas en access que se llama tblClientes y tblventa , cada vez que se hace una vente se pone el id del cliente (obviamente en c# en un combobox me muestra los nombre y no el id y en el grid una consulta para que me muestre los nombres) okey , el problema aqui es el siguiente tengo un textbox el cual cada vez que el usuario vaya escribiendo una letra pues me muestre los registros ya sea que empiezen con esa letra o terminen , eso lo hago mediante el evento keyup y ese resultado del query se deberia mostrar en el grid pero no me muestra absolutamente nada , raro es que ese query al depurar lo ejecuto en access y si me muestra un resultado pero aca no y si le escribo un nombre completo si me muestra algo pero esa no es la idea , la idea es que si el usuario no recuerda como escribio el nombre ya sea con mayuscula o minuscula me muestre resultados , alguien puede ayudarme por favor? muchas gracias de antemano adjunto codigo , tablas e imagenes.
[image: aqui deberia de mostrar en el segundo gridview el resultado ya que lo tengo para pruebas]

```
 private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //solo prueba, recuerda usar la tabla de ventas desglose en esta parte

        string texto = textBox1.Text;
        string QueryNombreClientes = "SELECT tblClientes.Nombre, tblVenta.Fecha, tblVenta.total FROM tblVenta INNER JOIN tblClientes ON tblVenta.idCliente = tblClientes.IdCliente WHERE tblClientes.Nombre LIKE '*" + texto + "*' ";
        string CadenaDeConexion = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\\Proalse\\BDProalse.accdb; persist security info = false";
        OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection(CadenaDeConexion);
        conexion.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(QueryNombreClientes,conexion);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        GridPrueba.DataSource = table;
        


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posdata: he intentado utilizar otro tipo de parametros leyendo la documentacion como %,[] etc pero aun asi no me muestra nada

Comment: Cambia los `*` por `%`

Comment: Para esto hay muchas indicacione en internet y la opción indicada para realizar esto, es El autoComplete Texbox este link te puede ayudar https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/autocomplete-textbox-in-windows-form/#:~:text=AutoComplete%20textbox%20is%20used%20for,text%20in%20a%20fastest%20way.

Answer (score 0):

Como te escribí en el comentario, y el articulo que esta en ingles puedes usar lo siguiente:
//Realizar o instanciar Autocompletecolection

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

Realizar un metodo de auto complete que es clave en lo que preguntas...

```
    public void Auto()  
     {  
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Name from tbl_empdetails order by name asc", con);  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        da.Fill(dt);  
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)  
        {  
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
            {  
                coll.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());  
            }  
        } else  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show("Name not found");  
        }  
        txtCliente.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;  
        txtCliente.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;  
        txtCliente.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;  
    }
```

por ultimo esta el llenado en el grid y aplicarlo en tu proyecto; que esta en el [articulo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/autocomplete-textbox-in-windows-form/#:%7E:text=AutoComplete%20textbox%20is%20used%20for,text%20in%20a%20fastest%20way.) mencionado y se llama fillgrid()